# UIImage: do I need to separate graphics for each orientation

Tags: ipad, uiimage, image-rotation

I'm creating an iPad magazine which includes full screen artwork graphics and I'm wondering how to handle the images during device rotation. Do I ship two versions of each image (one 1024x768px and one 768x1024px) or I can just ship one 1024x1024px and clip its contents to fit the the device orientation.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single 1024x1024px image.  Make a UIView (or use the main view in your UIViewController) and set it to stretch to fit the screen in either orientation. Also set the UIView to clip subviews.  Put in a UIImageView that doesn't resize and make it 1024x1024px.  The settings of the flexible spacing on the UIImageView and its position in the UIView will determine which part of the image gets shown.

For example, to always have the image centered, give all sides of the UIImageView flexible spacing and center it initially in the UIView.  To always show the top-left portion, fix the top and left sizes and align the top-left corner of the UIIMageView with the top-left corner of its parent UIView.

Comment: Doesn't seem like I can manage to get this behavior. Specifically I'm trying to handle device rotation for a UIScrollView with UIImageView subviews and I'm not sure how to accomodate landscape and vertical image orientation.

Comment: Since you're putting the views in a UIScrollView, you have to be careful to make sure that the UIView (as described above) is properly set to resize.  If you want the images to be the same size as the UIScrollView, you just need to set the UIView to expand in both directions, but be fixed to all of the edges (i.e. not have flexible spacing on any edge).  Alternatively, you can resize the UIView manually (by changing the frame or bounds) in your view controller when the orientation changes.  If you follow my instructions above, when you resize the UIView, the image will be cropped appropriately